# discord.py: Why isn't my join message working?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am stumped on why my join message isn't working! I have the discord.py library installed, and I am really confused! I have other code below it, but it shouldn't effect the above.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Player has joined")
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(800395922764070942)
    await channel.send(f'{member} has joined!')
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!loser'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello loser! Nice to meet you.')
    elif message.content.startswith('!bruh'):
        await message.channel.send('BRUHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!')

client.run("Where my token is")
```

Edited to show entire code. (Sorry for the stupid bruh things, they run perfectly but I just wanted to test some things..)

Comment: I've removed my previous answer and added the working solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to recent changes in discord.py (1.5.0) you now need to use intents. Intents enable to track things that happen.

First you need to enable it on the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) (where you created your bot). When you're there, select your application, go to the bot section, scroll down and tick the box.

[image: Tick server members intent]

Then in your code you need to add this at the top :

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

You will now be able to receive events like *on_member_join*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `get_channel` line from

```
    channel = client.get_channel(800395922764070942)
```

to

```
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(800395922764070942)
```

Comment: I've done this and it doesn't do anything.